# My Ajax call for my submit button does not work?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am building a form with the form builder but I can't even get my button to use its ajax function to callback. Instead of doing a normal ajax call on the page, it reloads the entire page.

What am I doing wrong here? The DPM function doesn't even run, so i'm assuming i'm not even triggering the ajax call, but I have copy pasted the function name into the callback, so i'm not sure why its not triggering on submit?

```
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship'] = array('#type' => 'container');
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['text'] = array('#type' => 'markup', '#markup' => '');
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['text']['#markup'] .= '<span class="SugList">Mentorships - <span id="mentorshipunconfirmed">Unconfirmed</span></span>';
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['button'] = array('#type' => 'button', '#button_type' => 'submit');
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['button']['#name'] = 'Mentorships';
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['button']['#attributes'] = array('data-title' => array('Mentorships'), 'class' => array('SA_Button'));
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['button']['#value'] = 'Confirm Mentorships';
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['button']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'erc360_completeness_report_suggested_actions_mentorship_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'mentorshipunconfirmed',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'none',
  );


  function erc360_completeness_report_suggested_actions_mentorship_ajax($form, $form_state){
      dpm("The AJAX FUNCTION has ran...");
      return $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['text']['#markup'] = '<span>confirm</span>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
$form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['button']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'erc360_completeness_report_suggested_actions_mentorship_ajax',
  'wrapper' => 'mentorshipunconfirmed',
  '#callback' => 'ajax_test',
  '#wrapper' => 'wrapper',
  'method' => 'replace',
  'effect' => 'fade',
);


function erc360_completeness_report_suggested_actions_mentorship_ajax($form, $form_state){
  dpm("The AJAX FUNCTION has ran...");
  $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['text']['#markup'] = '<span>confirm</span>';
  return $form['suggested_actions']['list']['mentorship']['text'];
}
```